# Nuxt SSR blog still calling API endpoints to get blog posts even thought its setup to be SSR

Tags: server-side-rendering, nuxt.js

been playing around with a simple blog built with JSONPlaceholder and Nuxt.js

Everything seems fine, I've got an archive and single blog posts working fine but when deployed on Netlify I can see that the browser is still doing API calls to JSONPlaceholder even though all the pages are built static and I can see they already have the content within the HTML.

I used the routes method within generate in the nuxt config to create the 100 html files based upon the JSONPlaceholder /posts results.

Here's the Netlify link: REMOVED.

And a public repo: https://bitbucket.org/oneupstudio/api-test/src/master/

Anything I've missed?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nuxt.js doesn't support 'full static generation' yet, check this [RFC](https://github.com/nuxt/rfcs/issues/22).

For now, you can use [this](https://github.com/DreaMinder/nuxt-payload-extractor) module in order to make your JSON requests static.

Comment: Ah interesting, didn't see that mentioned when reading up about everything. Thanks.

Comment: This is not a correct statement. Currenty one can do proper static wesbites with Nuxt. RFC's title is indeed a bit misleading. See my answer please

Answer (score -1):

Nuxt currenty supports proper static generation of websites. Although one has to be aware of payload param in asyncData. So if payload is present that indicates that static generator is at work and no api calls should be made in this case:

```
async asyncData ({ params, error, payload }) {
  if (payload) return { user: payload }
  else return { user: await backend.fetchUser(params.id) }
}
```

Read more on this [here](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-generate#routes).

---

[RFC](https://github.com/nuxt/rfcs/issues/22) mentioned by @DreadMinder  will further improve on this, but you can already do full static websites with Nuxt.

Comment: Have you tried this approach yourself? Could you show a working example? Because as far as I know, this payload-feature you mentioned, won't help to get rid of client-navigation requests to API. Its only meant to speed up 'generate' command (by fetching data in one request instead of request-per-page).

Comment: I have been using the code above and other techniques on a number of nuxt projects to work without any client side api calls. Yes, it is not that simple and that will be improved by RFC mentioned, but nevertheless it can be done with current Nuxt.